# BigCommerce stencil init error loading

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to customize a marketplace theme (Peak Standard).  I have followed all of the steps pointed out here. https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/downloading-and-customizing-marketplace-themes

But when I try to run stencil init I get the following errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

JavaScript Bundling Started...
Potentially unhandled rejection [8] Error: Error loading "js/app" at file:C:/Use                               rs/Dusten/Desktop/BC-DEV/assets/js/app.js

Error loading "npm:babel-core@5.6.15/browser.js" at file:C:/Users/Dusten/Desktop                               /BC-DEV/assets/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.6.15/browser.js.js

Error loading "npm:babel-core@5.6.15/browser.js" from "npm:babel-core@5.6.15" at                                file:C:/Users/Dusten/Desktop/BC-DEV/assets/jspm_packages/npm/babel-core@5.6.15.                               js

ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Dusten\Desktop\BC-DEV\assets\jspm_packages\npm\babel-core                               @5.6.15\browser.js.js'
    at Error (native)

Comment: This is an issue we've been seeing on windows when customizing a marketplace theme. We're looking into it.

Comment: Thank you for the response Alyss.

Comment: @Alyss I'm seeing this issue when customising a marketplace theme. Has this been resolved? The solution below seems to work for init but I think it causes problems when I try to create a bundle, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410833/bigcommerce-stencil-bundle-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this error but i managed to avoid this error by editing config.js file. you need to replace this path

```
" *":" *.js" to  " *":"dist/ *.js"
```

Also pleae make sure there is no space.
I am facing another issue at local no js is running. if anyone can help