# BigCommerce stencil bundle error

Tags: bigcommerce

[BigCommerce stencil init error loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059706/bigcommerce-stencil-init-error-loading) helped me resolve an init error that I was seeing but now I'm seeing the following.

```
root@23c28dbe0af1:/Runway-1.2.0# stencil bundle
Validating theme...
    SCSS Parsing Started...
    Template Parsing Started...
    Language Files Parsing Started...
    Building Theme Schema File...
    Generating Manifest Started...
    JavaScript Bundling Started...
    failed  -- Error loading "js/app" at file:/Runway-1.2.0/assets/dist/js/app.js
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Runway-1.2.0/assets/dist/js/app.js'
Potentially unhandled rejection [7] Error: Error loading "js/app" at file:/Runway-1.2.0/assets/dist/js/app.js
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Runway-1.2.0/assets/dist/js/app.js'
at Error (native)
ok -- Language Files Parsing Finished
ok -- SCSS Parsing Finished
ok -- Manifest Generation Finished
ok -- Theme Schema Building Finished
ok -- Template Parsing Finished
ok -- Zipping Files Finished
Bundled saved to: /Runway-1.2.0/Runway - IDH-1.2.0.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the files were bundled successfully to a zip file in your theme directory: "/Runway-1.2.0/Runway - IDH-1.2.0.zip". Were you able to upload and test the theme?

In your theme directory try upgrading using the command: 
`npm install -g bigcommerce/stencil-cli`